# POST Request in PHP is not returning anything

Tags: php, curl, post

I am trying to use Thycotic PAM API. According to their documentation, The following is a sample HTTP POST request. The placeholders shown need to be replaced with actual values.

```
POST /SecretServer/webservices/SSWebservice.asmx/GetUser HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.3.242
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: length

token=string&userId=string
```

I can get token string and user ID from the app. With this data, following is the PHP code I am trying

```
$url = 'https://192.168.3.242/SecretServer/webservices/SSWebservice.asmx/GetUser';
$data = array(
    'token' => 'token_string', 
    'userId' => 8
);

// use key 'http' even if you send the request to https://...
$options = array(
    'http' => array(
        'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'content' => http_build_query($data)
    )
);
$context  = stream_context_create($options);
$result = json_decode(file_get_contents($url, false, $context));
if ($result === FALSE) { /* Handle error */ }

var_dump($result);
```

I also tried this way:

```
function curl_get_contents($url)
{
  $ch = curl_init($url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
  $data = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
  return $data;
}

$url = 'https://192.168.3.242/SecretServer/webservices/SSWebservice.asmx/GetUser?token=token_string&userId=8 HTTP/1.1';

$json = json_decode(curl_get_contents($url));

var_dump($json);
```

Both of them are returning nothing. Any suggestion is much appreciated.

Comment: Your `curl` version doesn't send a `POST` request and doesn't send the parameters.

Comment: Thanks. I am new to this. Can you please suggest more details?

Comment: There must be tutorials on how to send POST data with curl.

Answer (score 0):

```
curl_setopt($ch ,CURLOPT_POST, 1);
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch ,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "token=string&userId=string");
```

you must use this parameters